# Are remote LUKS volumes mounted locally with sshfs made visible to remote users?

Tags: luks, sshfs, privacy

I created an encrypted volume with `LUKS` and uploaded it to a remote directory on an untrusted host.

I can mount it locally though. I first mount the remote directory locally with `sshfs` and then open my volume with  `cryptsetup` as if it were a local file.

```
$ sshfs user@host: remote/
# cryptsetup luksOpen remote/disk.img disk
$ mount /dev/mapper/disk mount_point/
```

My question is: do I thereby make whatever is in `mount_point/` visible to users on the remote host? Also, are commands I execute in a directory mounted through `sshfs` transparent to administrators on the remote host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remote host sees nothing but the (encrypted) reads and writes to the file.